# Puppeteer - how do I Identify input with no ID

Tags: html, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am attempting to fill in the persons name field on a page using puppeteer but cannot find the ID

```
<input placeholder="Enter Persons Name" type="text" data-marker="root/appPage/create/form/nameInput" class="sc-bdnxRM sc-dlMDgC sc-csTbgd jaediC hjOJya" value="Hello world">
```

How do I change "Hello World" without knowing the input's ID?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if another attribute of input is consistent in this site and try to use it (like a group of classes, the "data-marker" attribute, and others)

Otherwise, if you don't trust in these attributes, you can see around that input's parent elements, and use a selector like "#fatherElementId > input", for example.